# Rspec Failures In Sample App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rspec

I was having these errors earlier and I added the

```
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
```

line to `user.rb` and it seemed to fix some functionality issues on my sample app in development and everything was going fine. I then decided to push it to heroku and that wasn't working until i removed the

```
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
```

line from my `user.rb`. Now the rspec fails are back. Is there something I'm missing? Any help is appreciated.

```
 ' c:\Sites\sample_app>bundle exec rspec spec/
including Capybara::DSL in the global scope is not recommended!
.F.............F......FF..FFF..

Failures:

  1) User pages signup with valid information should create a user
     Failure/Error: expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)

       count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:46:in `block (4 levels) in <top (requi
red)>'

  2) User
     Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
       expected #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_
at: nil, password_digest: nil, password: nil> to be valid, but got errors: Passw
ord can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters), Name can't
be blank, Email can't be blank, Email is invalid, Password confirmation can't be
 blank
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User when email address is already taken
     Failure/Error: user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `upcase' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:79:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) User when email format is valid should be valid
     Failure/Error: @user.should be_valid
       expected #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: "user@foo.COM", created_at: ni
l, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil, password: nil> to be valid, but got er
rors: Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters),
Name can't be blank, Password confirmation can't be blank
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:71:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:69:in `each'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:69:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) User return value of authenticate method with valid password
     Failure/Error: it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:43:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6) User return value of authenticate method with invalid password
     Failure/Error: let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("i
nvalid") }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:49:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  7) User return value of authenticate method with invalid password
     Failure/Error: let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("i
nvalid") }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:50:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.37081 seconds
31 examples, 7 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:45 # User pages signup with valid infor
mation should create a user
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:19 # User
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:83 # User when email address is already taken
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:67 # User when email format is valid should be
valid
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:43 # User return value of authenticate method w
ith valid password
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:49 # User return value of authenticate method w
ith invalid password
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:50 # User return value of authenticate method w
ith invalid password'
```

Comment: show your `spec` and past code on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/jZnPPU2H - That's the code from `user_spec.rb`

Answer (score 0):

You have many mistake on your `spec`

```
2) User Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
```

Model not valid because not save

```
3) User when email address is already taken
```

This fault because model not saved

Understand [valid](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Validations/valid%3F)?

`valid?(context = nil)`

Runs all the specified validations and returns true if no errors were added otherwise false.

```
my_person = Person.new(params[:person])
my_person.valid?
# => false

my_person = Person.create(params[:person])
my_person.valid?
# => true

my_person.errors.add('login', 'can not be empty') if my_person.login == ''
my_person.valid?
# => false
```

and so much more just read errors

Comment: "This fault because model not saved" What does that mean? I'm new to this so could you elaborate a little more? when I use ` attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation` in 'user.rb' everything passes? Does that line override all of my rspec or something?